# Why I get the equation that I've written back instead of the solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, wolfram-alpha

I have this equation that I've written in Mathematica. I don't know why I get the same equation back instead of a solution. Is the syntax correct? BTW, v is energy, L is angular momentum, a takes the values 0 and 1 only and d is a whole number beginning with 2. I don't know how to define these values neither. I'm just trying to get a general solution then put different values. hope somebody could suggest something here. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IbMM.png)

Answer (score 2):

You made a type and put `DSolvv[]` instead of `DSolve[]`

Comment: sorry for that, I selected all the E's and changed them to v thought maybe Mathematica understand my E which is energy as the exponential. during the process of finding all the E's and substituting with something else (in my case v) that happened, the issue is the same thou. I updated the photo

Comment: @DannyNelson perhaps  it is too complex for Mathematica to deal with. Possible to simplify somehow or numerically solve?

Comment: I'll try numerically later, and I think this is as simple as it could be. I haven't made any syntax mistakes? when Mathematica returns the equation itself? I'm just trying to make sure if I have done something wrong here

Comment: @amWhy actually it does; mathematica's standard way to respond with what it does not understand is repeat it. OP asked why he is getting the same equation back, and the answer is -- because of the typo, mathematica did not understand and just returned the input

Comment: Thanks for the info, @gt6989b  I will delete my comment!  I see you are indeed correct.